# iTextSharp PDFAction.PrintDialog not working in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext, microsoft-edge

I noticed today that the PDF viewer within Microsoft's Edge browser is not allowing iTextSharp's `PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG)` command to work.  I create my PDFs in code and add this action call to the PDF so the print dialog window will appear after opening the PDF.  It works fine in Adobe Acrobat, IE & Chrome.  Here is an example of the PDF I created which you can open to test the various PDF viewers:

[PDF Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByMk9A-_4XPhaHNKTmJabUFvWTg/view?usp=sharing)

Let me know if anyone else has experienced this issue and if there is any way around it.  I'd much prefer not to have to move away from iTextSharp's library just to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG` is a JavaScript action and apparently Edge doesn't support it and/or general JS commands. (I haven't confirmed the lack of JS support yet bu I'm seeing rumblings about it.) If you [look at the source](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfAction.cs#L188) you'll see that iText is just injecting the simplest of JS code possible into the document's open action:

```
this.print(true);
```

So this isn't a problem with iText in any way, this is just a limitation of Microsoft's Edge PDF renderer. Switching to another PDF library wouldn't solve this problem, either.

*(Go Jacks!)*

Comment: Chris - thanks a bunch for the input and I had no idea we were now in a similar line of work.  Now I know I have a resource out there, especially for PDF related issues.  Take care and yes, GO JACKS!